# How to split contenteditable contents based on the caret position

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Question 1

Let's assume this is the inner content of a contenteditable element

```
abc def ghi j|kl mno pqr
```

And the cursor is between j and k. How do I split the contents in two to have the contents before the cursor which are

abc def ghi j

And the contents after the cursor

```
kl mno pqr
```

### Question 2

I also want to get the position of the cursor to the parent element

```
cursorX = $parentEl.width() - position of cursor from left;
cursorY = $parentEl.height() - position of cursor from top;
```

Comment: **Question 2** look here at the example: https://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/

Comment: Question 1 you can get position of cursor using `window.getSelection().anchorOffset` . Get text of that element. Split the string from zero to cursor position & cursor position to last character of string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For Question 1

```
cursorPos = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
allContents = document.getElementById('element').innerHTML;
contentsBeforeCursor = allContents.substring(0, cursorPos);
contentsAfterCursor = allContents.substring(cursorPos, allContents.length);
```

If Your contenteditable element contain HTML elements. You need to get the caret position ignoring the HTML tags and select only the text contents not the html content. so you can use this below

```
node = document.getElementById('element');
cursorPos = getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(node);
allContents = node.innerText;
contentsBeforeCursor = allContents.substring(0, cursorPos);
contentsAfterCursor = allContents.substring(cursorPos, allContents.length);

function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var caretOffset = 0;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
        preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
        caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return caretOffset;
}
```

### For Question 2

```
var coords = getSelectionCoords(),
pageX = coords.x,
pageY = coords.y;
elTop = $('#element').offset().top;
elLeft = $('#element').offset().left;
posFromTop = pageY - elTop;
posFromLeft = pageX - elLeft;

function getSelectionCoords() {
    win = window;
    var doc = win.document;
    var sel = doc.selection, range, rects, rect;
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            x = range.boundingLeft;
            y = range.boundingTop;
        }
    } else if (win.getSelection) {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            // Fall back to inserting a temporary element
            if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
                var span = doc.createElement("span");
                if (span.getClientRects) {
                    // Ensure span has dimensions and position by
                    // adding a zero-width space character
                    span.appendChild( doc.createTextNode("\u200b") );
                    range.insertNode(span);
                    rect = span.getClientRects()[0];
                    x = rect.left;
                    y = rect.top;
                    var spanParent = span.parentNode;
                    spanParent.removeChild(span);

                    // Glue any broken text nodes back together
                    spanParent.normalize();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find answer for question 1 here:

```js
function doIt() {
  var res = document.getElementById("someId").selectionStart
  var res2 = document.getElementById("someId").value.substring(0, res)
  var res3 = document.getElementById("someId").value.substring(res)
  console.log(res2);
  console.log(res3)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="someId" onclick="doIt()" value="abc def" />
```

Comment: OP is asking explicitly for a solution when the text is placed on a contenteditable element, not an input.